# I have the following json. I need to put it into a textview in android but I cant figure it out

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

This is the output from php in POSTMAN

```
{"questions":[{"question":"Berlin"}]}
```

I have attempted this with volley using a string request in android but with no luck. I have been at this for hours and cannot seem to figure it out at all. Currently with the following code the textview just sets to "json error". I'm sure its something silly but I cannot seem to fix it after looking for ages at my screen and trying lots of different methods I would be eternally grateful for a little help.

**Here is the android code**

```
private void getQuestion() {

    String url = "http://localhost/Articulate/getQuestion.php?category=" + category.getText().toString() + "&& game_id=" + game_id.getText().toString();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(com.example.conn.articulate.Play.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Play.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String questionRes="";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("questions");
        JSONObject q = result.getJSONObject(0);
        questionRes = q.getString("question");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        questionRes="Json error";
    }
    question.setText(questionRes);
}
```

**Stack**

```
2605/com.example.conn.articulate W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for question 08-21 17:28:54.500 2605-2605/com.example.conn.articulate W/System.err: at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389) 08-21 17:28:54.500 
2605-2605/com.example.conn.articulate W/System.err: at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584) 08-21 17:28:54.500 2605-
2605/com.example.conn.articulate W/System.err: at com.example.conn.articulate.Play.showJSON(Play.java:124) 08-21 17:28:54.500 2605-2605/com.example.conn.articulate
```

PHP OUTPUT

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {


//makes it work
$category = (string)filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category');
$game_id = $_GET['game_id'];

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$query = "SELECT question FROM questions WHERE category = '$category' and NOT EXISTS
(SELECT  *
    FROM    answered_questions
    WHERE   game_id='.$game_id.'
    )ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1";

$result = (mysqli_query($con, $query));

$jsonData = array();
while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $jsonData[] = $array;
}

$data = array(
    'questions' =>
        $jsonData);
echo json_encode( $data);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($con);
```

}

Comment: There is your answer. It doesn't have a JSONObject inside the array. The JSONArray is essentially empty. Will provide an answer shortly to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, from your comment it is quite clear why the Exception is happening. It is because your `JSONArray` questions come out empty. And thus `q.getString("question")` fails with an exception since there is no JSONObject at index 0 to begin with. Please clarify from your php server if that should happen ever. Anyway, even if it does here is some code to tell the user that no questions were found. (You can do something else in the `else` block too like say hide a view or show a new view)

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("questions");
        if (result.length()) > 0 { 
           JSONObject q = result.getJSONObject(0);
           questionRes = q.getString("question");
        } else {
          questionRes = "No More Questions"
        }            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        questionRes="Json error";
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
try {
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("questions");
JSONObject q = result.getJSONObject(0);
questionRes = q.getString("question");
}
```

You are passing "question" but the array name is "questions" with a 's' at the end.

Comment: sorry thats just a typo in my question ive actually played around alot with it

Comment: @cmc12345 edit your questions to show that your have indeed made a typo `here` and not `in your code`, and also indicate what is line Play:124

Comment: play is just the name of the activity

Comment: @cmc12345 i get that, Play.java is a file that has a line 124 as per the stack.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the response is received, you should check the received response with Toast or Log. If the response is as expected, do the json parsing and make sure you leave no trailing spaces inside " ".

Answer (score -1):

I have exactly a json like this. Use this code:

```
JSONObject jObject = null;
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("questions");
                JSONObject jsonObject=jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String question = jsonObject.getString("question");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

make sure that there is no extra " at the beggining and the end of your response string.

Comment: a perfect duplicate of prior answer, less the explanation.

Comment: still nothing :( is you php output exactly the same?

Comment: @cmc12345 yes it is , Toast your response here , maybe there is something wrong with your json .